# ksh -x with dirname

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

The directory which contains the script is in the PATH variable.

Script is only have the following lines:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "Dirname: $(dirname $0)"
echo "Basename: $(basename $0)"
```

Normally running it and then in debug mode:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ test.sh
Dirname: /home/user/scripts
Basename: test.sh
[user@localhost ~]$ ksh -x test.sh
+ dirname test.sh
+ echo 'Dirname: .'
Dirname: .
+ basename test.sh
+ echo 'Basename: test.sh'
Basename: test.sh
```

Current directory is:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ pwd
/home/user
[user@localhost ~]$
```

My question is, why dirname changes if I run a script in debug mode with `ksh -x` ?

If I set the first line in the script to `#!/bin/ksh -x` then it works perfectly.

Is it somehow related that with `ksh -x`, the linux forks a new shell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not changing a directory. Running `test.sh` without leading paths makes the shell search for it in the `PATH` directory. In this case `test.sh` was found in `/home/user/scripts` making its complete path as `/home/user/scripts/test.sh`. Running `dirname` on it, you would get `/home/user/scripts`. However with `ksh -x test.sh`, the script is not searched in `PATH` and you only get to run the one on the current directory making the value of `$0` to `test.sh`. Running `dirname` on it, you'd only get `.`.

It's likely that you have `/home/user/scripts/test.sh` which is ran on the first instance. And another same script `/home/user/test.sh` or perhaps a link to `/home/user/scripts/test.sh` which is ran on the second instance.

If you want your commands to be targetting same file, specify their paths explicitly:

```
ksh /home/user/scripts/test.sh
ksh -x /home/user/scripts/test.sh
```

Or

```
ksh ./test.sh
ksh -x ./test.sh
```

This may go similar as well:

```
ksh test.sh
ksh -x "$(which test.sh)"
```

Comment: Well, the script is only located in /home/user/scripts/test.sh. No other copy/link is existing

Comment: @batiz What's your current directory? Have you tried my suggestions? Also, can you tell me the output of `which test.sh`?

Comment: Nevertheless, just running `test.sh` would make the shell search for it in PATH. And running `ksh test.sh` or `ksh -x test.sh` would make it run the script in current directory with `$0` set to `test.sh`. Ksh doesn't change directories. Only the value of `$0`. You're still running it in the current directory no matter what script you tried to run.

Comment: which output: `[user@localhost ~]$ which test.sh
~/scripts/test.sh
[user@localhost ~]$`

Comment: So that shows it. Simply running `test.sh` runs `/home/user/scripts/tests.sh`. But `ksh test.sh` runs the `test.sh` on the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

First command is run with default shell (`Bash`?) while the second one is run with `ksh`. This may explain the different

Comment: sorry, that was a misstype, corrected it, I'm only using ksh.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out what's going on.

From dirname manual :

`Print NAME with its trailing /component removed; if NAME contains no /’s, output ‘.’ (meaning the current directory).`

So I solved it with this line:

`DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"`

It always gets the script's directory and works with relative and absolute path either.